# PDF thumbs not showing in Explorer

Tags: windows-8, pdf, thumbnails

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit

At some point I stopped getting thumbs for my PDF files in Windows Explorer.
I suspected that some thumb cache size may be involved as I have huge collection of PDF files, but I'm not sure as I don't know how thumbs are generated except that some shell extension should be in use. And it just may be some program I have installed misbehaves, like for example Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader...

- PDF extension is associated with `Microsoft Reader`
- In Windows Explorer options, option `Always show icons, never thumbnails` is unchecked
- In "System Properties > Performance options", `Show thumbnails instead of icons` is checked

These are settings that may influence thumbs as suggested by Google. Additionally I may provide log from Sysinternals' autoruns on demand.

What else could be wrong, as I still can't get PDF thubms

Answer (score 1):

The probably easiest (and btw for me the only one working) way was to install Foxit Reader 7. Choose to install the main programm (mandatory) + shell extensions (anything else is not necessary). You don't need to make Foxit the default viewer for PDF files.

(Tried with Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit)

Comment: Thanks, i just tested and it worked!!!! Don't forget to check "Shell Extension" (i had to install it twice :P forgot to check it) :) Adobe Reader 9, and after that... Foxit Reader 7.2.5